# Start up Docker container in VS Code when remote debug by pressing F5

Tags: python-3.x, docker, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, vscode-debugger

I want to remote debug a docker container and spin it up when pressing the F5 (debug). It works just fine expept for that one particular problem. The container is started but the shell does not quit and hence nothing happens. Python source code is just to check whether it works:

```
import ptvsd
import time
import os

print("Waiting to attach")

address = ('0.0.0.0', 3000)
ptvsd.enable_attach(address)
ptvsd.wait_for_attach()

time.sleep(2)
print('something changed')
print("end")
```

I've tried to run it with the preLaunchTask of **launch.json**:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Terminal (integrated)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "DOCKER (Remote Debug)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 3000,
            "host": "localhost",
            "pathMappings": [
                {"localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}", "remoteRoot": "/app/"}
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "start_docker_compose",
            "redirectOutput": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Additinionally, I've created a **task.json** to run the container:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "start_docker_compose",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": [
                "docker run -it -p 5000:5000 dockertest",

            ],
            "problemMatcher": []

        }
    ]
}
```

It works just fine until the shell command starts up the container and the string "Waiting to attach" shows up. Then nothing happens because the shell waits and therefore the remote debugging process can't connect either. Is there a workaround (I've tried a bash as well with the same result) or am I wrong and there is a much smoother solution.
Would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.